# Retrieve child node value from firebase with push keys as parent

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem in retrieving data from my firebase database. The data is arranged like in this way, in my root ref node I have a child as "FirstReply" which have children nodes as message Ids, for each messageIds there are inners nods (push keys) and values as shown in figure.

[image]

I want to retrieve the value of child sellerID in each PushID node and like to compare with current userID, but when I wrote the code like this

```
RootRef.child("FirstReply").child(Enquiry_MessageID).
    addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      String returnSellerID=  snapshot.child("sellerId").getValue().toString();
      if(returnSellerID==current_user_Id) {
         //my remaining code

      }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

I am getting an error like:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

and my app is crashing. I can have value of messageID in each instances but the push values is different in each cases. Is there is any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to loop over the child nodes of the `snapshot` you get:

```
RootRef.child("FirstReply").child(Enquiry_MessageID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) { //  loop over the child nodes
      String returnSellerID = child.child("sellerId").getValue().toString();
      if(returnSellerID.equals(current_user_Id)) { //  use equals to compare strings
        //my remaining code
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    throw error.toException(); //  never ignore errors
  }
});
```